# Docker Solr container on Azure - write.lock file is being changed by an external force at 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z

Tags: azure, docker, solr

We are currently deploying our application onto Microsoft Azure. As a part of this we are running `docker-solr 8.2`.

We've found that, occasionally, attempting to add or remove an item from the index will cause solr to fall over and endlessly throw the exception below.

It seems that some process is modifying the `write.lock` file in such a way that it believes it was modified at the epoch. (`Underlying file changed by an external force at 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`)

Restarting solr fixes the issue for a while though it will eventually happen again.

Stack trace is as follows:

```
2019-10-02 12:21:56.798 ERROR (qtp2082351661-25) [   x:global] o.a.s.h.RequestHandlerBase org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Server error writing document id 2133 to the index
    at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:241)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessor.processAdd(RunUpdateProcessorFactory.java:76)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:55)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.doLocalAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:257)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.doVersionAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:487)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.lambda$versionAdd$0(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:337)
    at org.apache.solr.update.VersionBucket.runWithLock(VersionBucket.java:50)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.versionAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:337)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.processAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:223)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessorFactory$LogUpdateProcessor.processAdd(LogUpdateProcessorFactory.java:103)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:55)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory$AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessor.processAdd(AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory.java:475)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:55)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:118)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:55)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:118)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:55)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:118)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:55)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:118)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:55)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldNameMutatingUpdateProcessorFactory$1.processAdd(FieldNameMutatingUpdateProcessorFactory.java:75)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:55)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:118)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:55)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.AbstractDefaultValueUpdateProcessorFactory$DefaultValueUpdateProcessor.processAdd(AbstractDefaultValueUpdateProcessorFactory.java:92)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JavabinLoader$1.update(JavabinLoader.java:110)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec$StreamingCodec.readOuterMostDocIterator(JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec.java:327)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec$StreamingCodec.readIterator(JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec.java:280)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.readObject(JavaBinCodec.java:336)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.readVal(JavaBinCodec.java:281)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec$StreamingCodec.readNamedList(JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec.java:235)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.readObject(JavaBinCodec.java:301)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.readVal(JavaBinCodec.java:281)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.unmarshal(JavaBinCodec.java:194)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec.unmarshal(JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec.java:126)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JavabinLoader.parseAndLoadDocs(JavabinLoader.java:123)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JavabinLoader.load(JavabinLoader.java:70)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.UpdateRequestHandler$1.load(UpdateRequestHandler.java:97)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:68)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:199)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2578)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:780)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:566)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:423)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:350)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1602)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1711)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1347)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1678)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1249)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:335)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:781)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:917)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
 Caused by: org.apache.lucene.store.AlreadyClosedException: this IndexWriter is closed
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.ensureOpen(IndexWriter.java:681)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.ensureOpen(IndexWriter.java:695)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.updateDocument(IndexWriter.java:1591)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.updateDocument(IndexWriter.java:1586)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.updateDocOrDocValues(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:964)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.doNormalUpdate(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:342)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc0(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:289)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:236)
    ... 79 more
 Caused by: org.apache.lucene.store.AlreadyClosedException: Underlying file changed by an external force at 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z, (lock=NativeFSLock(path=/solr_config/data/global/data/index/write.lock,impl=sun.nio.ch.FileLockImpl[0:9223372036854775807 exclusive valid],creationTime=2019-10-02T11:52:59Z))
    at org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory$NativeFSLock.ensureValid(NativeFSLockFactory.java:191)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.LockValidatingDirectoryWrapper.createOutput(LockValidatingDirectoryWrapper.java:43)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.TrackingDirectoryWrapper.createOutput(TrackingDirectoryWrapper.java:43)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.compressing.CompressingStoredFieldsWriter.<init>(CompressingStoredFieldsWriter.java:112)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.compressing.CompressingStoredFieldsFormat.fieldsWriter(CompressingStoredFieldsFormat.java:128)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene50.Lucene50StoredFieldsFormat.fieldsWriter(Lucene50StoredFieldsFormat.java:183)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.StoredFieldsConsumer.initStoredFieldsWriter(StoredFieldsConsumer.java:39)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.StoredFieldsConsumer.startDocument(StoredFieldsConsumer.java:46)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain.startStoredFields(DefaultIndexingChain.java:367)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain.processDocument(DefaultIndexingChain.java:403)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriterPerThread.updateDocument(DocumentsWriterPerThread.java:250)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.updateDocument(DocumentsWriter.java:495)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.updateDocument(IndexWriter.java:1594)
    ... 84 more
```

We only have one solr instance and our write.lock and all other config/data files are in blob storage on azure that should only accessible by this instance.

I'm happy to provide any further information that might be helpful.